# Adjust width with respect to another element

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this layout:

```
...
    <LinearLayout
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="60dp">

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/n_alb"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

            <EditText 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" <!-- ?? -->
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>
...
```

I want the `TextView`'s width to be `wrap_content` whereas the `EditText`'s width fills the rest of the space in the parent.

I know I can use `weightSum` and `layout_weight` but isn't there another way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes you can do this at run time with calculation of the screen size and your layout size and all that you need to calculate and need to adjust your size of layout, but that is also gonna be fixed size you need to give you can use Wrap_content and adjust the way you want.

Comment: Why would you not want to use the weights? :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/yourtextview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/n_alb" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/yourtextview" >
    </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you have to longer text in textview then you can use it simple way.**

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Android Development Android Development"
            android:background="#fff000"
            android:id="@+id/textView2" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="hello developer How are you"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```